Angular set custom header for all requests
I have to add custom header to each request sent by angular to back-end.
It's easy for httpClient, It can be done by adding interceptor. but what about static files.
so I tried using webpack, like:
devServer: {
    headers: {
      'X-Custom-Test': 'bar',
    },
    proxy: [
      {
        context: ['/api'],
        target: 'https://localhost:3000',
        secure: false,
        headers: {
          'X-Custom-Foo': 'bar',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer '
        },
      },
    ],
}

but it's not worked, what could I do?
Edit:
I want any url to my server to have a custom header:
api call, img url, video url ...
httpClient.get('/api/profile/get')

    <img alt="" src="/res/images/example.png" >
    
    <video>
    <source src="/res/videos/ex.mp4" >
    </video>

so any url called to my server

set it directly in your http call

That seems very weird -- what are you trying to achieve?

u cant add header info for static url! only get param and update nginx to set header if get parameter used

yes I think that. I had to add pipe to all src of tag img
